# AutoLISP: Select text inside closed polylines and define block atributtes with that text

Tags: text, lisp, block, autocad, autolisp

I have a floor-plan drawing with several rooms defined by enclosed polylines. There are several text annotations inside each polyline (room-number, room-name, etc).
How can i make a routine thats scans the drawing, builds a selection-set that finds each polyline (resides on a specific layer) and inserts a block (room_stamp) with attributes corresponding to those annotations.
So for example, for every room it would insert the block "room_stamp" inside the polyline, grab the text inside the polyline which belongs to the layer "room_name" and change the attribute "room_name" inside the block to match it.

Any help would be much apreciatted as I am just starting with LIPS routines

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to obtain a selection set of all closed polylines residing on the target layer - for this you would use the `ssget` function with the `X` mode string argument (to scan the entire drawing database with no user input), and a filter list argument filter on entity type (DXF group 0), and layer (DXF group 8), and optionally on the bit-coded DXF group 70 to restrict the selection to closed polylines only - you may wish to refer to my [ssget Function Reference](http://lee-mac.com/ssget.html) to assist with the construction of this expression.

On obtaining a selection set of polylines on the target layer, you would then iterate over this set (there are [many methods](http://lee-mac.com/selsetprocessing.html) to do this), and for each polyline you have one of two options:

1. Obtain a window polygon/crossing polygon selection set of all text (perhaps restricted to a target layer) by supplying the `ssget` function with the `WP` or `CP` mode string, the set of polyline vertex coordinates, and an appropriate filter list.
2. Obtain a selection set of *all* candidate text objects within the active layout/viewport and use a ray-casting algorithm or similar to test whether the insertion point of each text object resides within the boundary of the polyline.

Method (1) is the easiest, but could also be the least reliable, as the graphical selection methods of the `ssget` function will only consider objects visible within the drawing area at the time of function evaluation - hence, for greater accuracy, you would first need to zoom to each polyline before acquiring the selection of the objects it encloses, and then restoring the previous view.

Method (2) is more reliable in that it is independent of the state of the graphical display in AutoCAD, but will be slower as it requires more calculation and iteration over the entire set of candidate text objects (unless you implement a divide & conquer technique through clever use of pre-sorting the set).

Upon acquiring the set of text objects residing within the polyline, you'll need some way to differentiate each text object in the set, so that you populate each attribute with the appropriate value. This will be completely dependent on your data - e.g. whether each item of data resides on its own layer (for example, do all of the room numbers reside on their own layer, and all room names on another?), or can you use pattern matching on the text content to identify a room number from a room name and other information?

With the appropriate values determined, it is relatively straightforward to insert a new attributed block reference (perhaps at the centroid of the polyline, or at the insertion point of one of the existing text objects) and populate the block attributes with the values acquired from the text - there are many existing examples of this.

Comment: Many thanks Lee Mac! Followed your tips to arrive to a solution.

Comment: You're welcome @user14693180 ! Please mark my answer as the solution if it sufficiently answered your question, so that the question appears as resolved for others viewing the site.